# What is the size of an MC mob head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to know the size of a mob head in MC so I can model a mask for my modelpack. Thanks a lot if you answer.

Comment: What do mean by size? Pixel dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

Mob heads are 8x8 pixels per side. However, mob heads are directly linked to the mob's texture. Therefore, to change, say, a creeper skull, you have to edit the creeper's texture. (creeper.png, under the creeper folder in entities)

Comment: Don't edit original file though, make a copy and use it via texture pack!

Comment: @AntoineHejlík He said he needs to make it for a model pack. I included the directory for the purpose of being able to put the texture under the right somewhat unusual) file directory.